# iOS charts - draw value only when highlighted

Tags: ios, charts, highlight, ios-charts

I want to highlight and show value only when tapping on the iOS-Chart.  I enabled the highlight but not the values because I only want them when tap and highlight

```
lineChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
lineChartDataSet.highlightEnabled = true
```

Do I need this function?

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {}
```

Comment: Yes you need to use the chartValueSelected function, inside that function code whatever you want to happen when a value is highlighted

Comment: thanks! I would like to show the value only when touching the screen.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Maruta did you manage to solve this?

Comment: actually not.. it doesn't seem an available feature in this iOS Chart library.  What I could only do is to show the values after first tap and then drag to show other values. But I still couldn't show the value ONLY while taping or dragging

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, but I think it's still actual for some developers.

If you want to show values, baloon or highlight bar only while user is touching a chart view you may catch a touch event with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

I instantiated new `TappableLineChartView` class from `LineChartView`. But you can work with `BarChartView` in the same way. Also if you don't want to instantiate new classes, you can incorporate `addTapRecognizer` and `chartTapped` functions in your view controller.

In my example, I show and hide values, but in the same manner, you can show and hide a balloon or another marker.

```
class TappableLineChartView: LineChartView {

    public override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addTapRecognizer()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addTapRecognizer()
    }

    func addTapRecognizer() {
        let tapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(chartTapped))
        tapRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func chartTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            // show
            let position = sender.location(in: self)
            let highlight = self.getHighlightByTouchPoint(position)
            let dataSet = self.getDataSetByTouchPoint(point: position)
            dataSet?.drawValuesEnabled = true
            highlightValue(highlight)
        } else {
            // hide
            data?.dataSets.forEach{ $0.drawValuesEnabled = false }
            highlightValue(nil)
        }
    }
}
```